# Are These Orthonormal Functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, orthonormal

Working through a text (self-learning, not homework), I reached this problem:

> Prove that the set of functions $\psi_n(x)=a^{-1/2}e^{i\pi nx/a}$ is orthonormal for integer $n$.

So that's a fairly straightforward problem, but I feel like I'm losing my mind. It's particularly clear that if, for two such functions $\psi_m, \psi_n$, the sum $n+m$ is odd, then:
$$
\int _{[0,a]}dx\;\psi^*_m \psi_n\ne 0,\;\; m\ne n
$$

Does the author mean to make $\psi_n=a^{-1/2}e^{i2\pi nx/a}$? I wish to believe so, but the previous definition is stated in the next two problems in the same way (as first written).

I seriously hope I'm not making any stupid mistakes, but I have a feeling it might be the case.

Comment: Are you sure the interval isn't $[-a,a]$?

Comment: @DavidH Yep, checked that first, and the textbook continually says $[0,a]$.

Comment: What's the text/page?

Comment: Text is McQuarrie Quantum Chemistry, Ch.3, problem 26; page 106.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo! We need the $2$, for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m\neq n$ we have

$$\int_0^a\psi_n \psi^*_m dx = \frac{1}{a}\int_0^a \exp \left( 2 \frac{ i \pi ( m-n) x}{a} \right) = \frac{1}{2 i \pi ( m-n)}\exp \left ( \frac{ 2i \pi ( m-n)x }{a} \right) \Big |_0^a =\frac{\exp[2 i \pi (m-n) ] -1}{i \pi ( m-n)}= 0 $$

If $m = n$, we have that

$$ \int_0^a\psi_n \psi^*_n dx = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a dx = 1$$

So it indeed is an orthonormal set of functions.

Comment: Fantastic, just making sure. I explicitly calculated the integral, too, to make sure I wasn't overlooking some random case, but it's an odd typo that continues throughout the rest of the problems.

Comment: I think the issue is he knew $\sin( \pi n x /a)$ and $\cos( \pi n x /a)$ were orthonormal on $[0,a]$ but the cross terms aren't, we need to double up to $[0,2a]$ to get rid of them.

Comment: Just figured that as you were typing it. Seems to be that is the case since he does correctly state that $\int_{[0,a]}\sin(m\pi x/a)\sin(n\pi x/a)=\frac{a}{2}\delta_{nm}$, with a similar statement using cosines previous to this problem.